# Creating a macro variable using SYSFUNC and INTNX

Tags: sas

I'm looking at some SAS code that I have been given for a university project, it's basically an exercise to get us comfortable with using macro variables. The code is as follows:

```
%LET my_date = 01OCT2001;
%LET my_date_2 = %SYSFUNC(INTNX('month','&my_date.'d,0,e),yymmn4.);
%PUT New date is &my_date_2.;
```

I have tried just about everything I can think of, I've changed the quotation marks every way imaginable. Whenever I check the log the output from PUT is always just '.', I'm new to SAS and can't find a similar question on online forums.

I think what the code wants to do is create another variable to store the date from the first variable in the 'yymmn4.' format.

Comment: 2001/10/01 is a bad date to be using for testing :(

Comment: If you are new to SAS why are you trying to use the macro language?  What is the actual use case?  Can't you just do it using SAS code instead of trying to learn two different languages at the same time?

Comment: My professor told us to @Tom

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. Do not use quotes for arguments when using `%sysfunc` with `intnx` (or other functions). The only exception to this are date literals, which do need quotes so SAS can know they are date literals. Because the macro function is already passing in values as a string, these arguments do not need to be quoted like a string.
2. Date literals can also be in double quotes. When using single quotes, macro variables do not resolve. This feature is designed so that you can use strings that contain % or & elsewhere within SAS without resolving them as macros or macro variables.

`%LET my_date_2 = %SYSFUNC(INTNX(month,"&my_date."d,0,e),yymmn4.);`

```
New date is 0110
```

Comment: I receive this error when I run your code:
ERROR: An error occurred evaluating a numeric function argument

ERROR: Invalid date constant "1"d

ERROR: The expression text was "1

Comment: Why did you set the macro variable MY_DATE to the string 1 if you wanted to use it as part of a date literal?